# Why is my layout messing up

Tags: html, css

I have an angular app, and in certain states, the layout errors. I have a fiddle here of a DOM snapshot of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/g8kjfj2g/

I don't understand why the two boxes in the top container aren't on the same line. They're both "display: inline-block" and have the same class. Compare here for a different DOM snapshot where two of the "parent-item" boxes exist on the same line: https://jsfiddle.net/wr10z3oc/

```
.parent-item {
display: inline-block;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: lightgray;
opacity: .7;
}
```

I think I have a missing symbol somewhere in my HTML but all my Sublime parsers can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `overflow:hidden` in `.parent-item` - https://jsfiddle.net/g8kjfj2g/1/

```
.parent-item {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    opacity: .7;
    overflow:hidden
}
```

Comment: That did work. Can you explain why the static node with the parent-item class was behaving differently than the ng-repeat nodes? Such a small amount of text in the child text node shouldn't overflow it.